# Android Activity Not found - never had before this error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, icons

I have a problem that i never had before. I have created an App with eclipse, so when I was finished I started it with eclipse,and everything does work. But when I start it by my self with the icon, there comes a toast message which says: activity not found. I haven´t any idea what to do because the Log says everything goes right. Eclipse can start my App, but i can´t?!

Please Help me!!

```
 `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.dered.ppg"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.7.1" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
    <activity android:name="PPGActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:launchMode="standard" android:label="@string/app_name" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="InfoActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name="PlanActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name="TerminActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name="SplashActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:icon="@drawable/ppglogo2" android:launchMode="standard" android:label="@string/app_name" android:enabled="true">
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

Comment: Please post your code, and log errors (if any.)

Comment: So you ran it on the emulator by clicking on the application icon after you ran it through eclipse? Or was this on your phone?

Comment: Also, post your manifest too please

Comment: It's only wrong app shortcut. Delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

1. verify that the activities can really be found on the given path , and that they are public .
2. update adt&sdk&eclipse&java
3. delete bin&gen folders , and do clean project
4. restart emulator (or re-create it) , restart eclipse/adt/OS.
5. change build order of the items (via the java build path).
6. try Lint . it might find the cause to the problem .
7. create a new project , see that it works , and put there your code.

Comment: i actually hoped that the last thing won't be needed , as this requires you to do a lot of moving of files.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the app from your device/emulator entirely and reinstalling from Eclipse.

Comment: Remove all that extra stuff from your splash activity so it's just <activity android:name="SplashActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />.

Comment: NO SORRY: i HAVE STILL THIS PROBLEM

Comment: It sounds like this isn't so much a problem with the manifest file then, but that your app does something that effectively kills itself, or at least crashes the app when you try to relaunch it. How many activities does your app have at this point? If it's just one can you edit your post to include it?

Comment: it has 5 Activitys and a task

Comment: If it helps you, I can Share you the download link for the project.

Comment: Guys I have found the solution!!! I created a new project, and just copied all the source codes and so on to the new project, and it just WORK now!!!!!!